# How to implement a dynamic filter with views in D7?

Tags: views, input-formats

I have a site where i have several main topics, each containing subtopics.  I've made views block which is shown on each of the pages of the main topics where you have two exposed filter options:
 - filter on main topic
 - filter on subtopic

For the filter on subtopic the idea is to ensure that only those subtopics are shown that reside under the selected main topic.  How can i do that?

Comment: found out that this blogpost answers my question perfectly:
http://bouteillenicolas.com/expertise-drupal/views-ajax-dynamic-dependent-exposed-filters